# Which one has the least amount of latency: powerline or 802.11AC?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, streaming, powerline-networking, 802.11ac

I want to steam stream from my PC to a stream mini on my living room next to my TV. Right now the latency is low-ish but less than ideal at 6ms.
For reference I have the gaming PC wirelessly connected with an 802.11ac adapter with very good signal strength at 5Ghz.
I am wondering whether it would be more helpful to add a 5Ghz 802.11ac adapter to the stream mini or just buy a powerline adapter and connect it to ethernet. 
Bandwidth is not too much of an issue, 10 Mbit/sec should be enough, but latency is key. Anyone has made any comparisons or have suggestions?

Comment: Powerline *should* have less latency in optimal conditions than wifi as it is wired.  However, it depends a lot on how clean / connected the power line is as to how much latency / throughput.  I suspect this question cannot be definitively answered because it is dependent on the environment.

Comment: I've read a lot of good and bad reviews. So many factors at play like distance, traversing floors, interference. How far is the router from TV?

Comment: You pretty much need to try both and see which is better in your situation.  Both are extremely dependent on your specific situation.  There is no way to predict.

Comment: So I did both. Maybe just out of curiosity I will try them in different scenarios and see how they behave. I could try at my parents or in-laws.
Anyway, In my apartment I found the following:
Powerline gave me a nice mostly constant 5ms of latency. 
If I plug my PC to ethernet and the stream mini to 802.11AC I get 3 to 50ms of latency (with an average of 8ms). 
If both ends are on 802.11 AC It goes from 10ms to 150 (with an average of 20ms)

What makes the experience of streaming so much better on powerline, however, is how the latency is steady and predictable.

Answer (score 4):

My experience with Powerline is that is has horrible latency:

```
50 packets transmitted, 49 received, 2% packet loss, time 49075ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 23.740/665.342/2039.040/449.964 ms, pipe 3
```

I am using cheap TP-LINK 100mbps devices. Producer claims 500mbps over powerline, but the devices have 100mpbs Ethernet interfaces.

EDIT: I was trying TP-LINK. I've bought now Fritz! 1200 with Gigabit ethernet, and the latency is still bad, except that it depends heavily on the traffic. Disclaimer: both times the devices were on separate phases, connected through a high-pass filter (phace coupler), and some 50m away.

Comment: This is more of a comment than an answer.

Comment: powerline has almost no latency.  I stream HD video through it.  Would never go back to wireless.  Your wiring must be bad.

Comment: @Keltari: I live in a freshly constructed building, and I don't argue with facts. Here the fact is the result of the ping.

Comment: @Keltari Latency wouldn't automatically be apparent while streaming video, unless it was realtime/gaming stuff -- total throughput would be the dominant factor. Powerline ethernet latency depends heavily on SNR, which can vary greatly.

Comment: "I live in a freshly constructed building" that also has bad wiring.